# Need some guidance understanding CSS targeting of classes

Tags: html, css

After googling quite a bit I haven't been able to find documentation that was specific, to be honest, I don't know how to phrase this question without getting an irrelevant response because I have no idea what the name of the item I am looking for is called. In my mind I'd call it a element/class selector.

When targeting specific elements to style I do not always get the result that I want due to the style not applying. For example in something like this:

```
<div class=box>
    <div class=smallerbox>

        <div class=something>It has some text in it</div>

    <div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to just be able to edit with CSS to look like this:

```
.something {color:#FFF}
```

But instead sometimes it doesn't work and I have to do this:

```
.box .smallerbox .something {color:#FFF}
```

Now the problem is I am not always sure how far back to go and I end up adding in extra stuff that I don't need or wasting time because I do not fully understand what I am doing. Adding `!important` doesn't always work either.

The reason I think I have to do this is because I am using bootstrap.css and this way I have to specifically target the class or it gets overridden by the parent class styles.

Am  I correct for thinking this way?

Any tips or methods to save me from madness of learning HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP through random guides and documentation would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: CSS Specificity, have a read:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is class/CSS specificity. This is a good start in understanding: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

But there are plenty of other articles online you can look at.

Basically a rule of thumb is not to over qualify your selectors (i.e. use the minimum needed). This way if you need to override a style later on you can be slightly more specific or add an extra class to add/override styles to the existing style.

When you nest your style references too much it soon becomes a nightmare to manage and you MUST try to avoid `!important` at all costs. If CSS is done correctly it shouldn't be needed.

Some libraries can set styles with certain class names and some do use long chains, so naming your classes becomes a difficult task too. But most shouldn't interfere too much as long as you load their CSS first and yours after.

Comment: Thanks so much for the link. Not only did it give me a new source of infomartion but it answered all my unasked questions in this matter.

Comment: No prblem, glad it helped. Good luck with the CSS!

Answer (score 0):

```
.box .smallerbox .something {color:#FFF}
```

means, give `color : #FFF` to `something` inside `smallerbox` which is kept inside `box`, so, this would be applied only to div named `something` for below

```
<!--   box
        |
        |
        |-------smallerbox
                    |
                    |
                    |-------something <= make this white -->
```

but when you say :

```
.something {color:#FFF}
```

it means, any `something` which has no `css` defined for it...check this fiddle for understanding better

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LdqgpL2/2/)